# declaration of 'OPairType::OPairType(int, int)' outside of class is not definition

Tags: c++, class, operators

The error I am getting is:

> declaration of 'OPairType::OPairType(int, int)' outside of class is not definition -fpermissive

Here is my full code:

Header File:

```
class OPairType{
private:
 int x;
 int y;
public:
 OPairType (int=0, int=0);
 int getX() const;
 int getY() const;
 void setX(int);
 void setY(int);
 void setValues(int, int);
 friend OPairType operator + (OPairType, OPairType);
 friend OPairType operator - (OPairType, OPairType);
 friend bool operator == (OPairType, OPairType);
 friend bool operator != (OPairType, OPairType);
 friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, OPairType);
```

And here is the .cpp code:

```
#include "OPairType.h"
#include <iostream>

OPairType::OPairType (int x, int y); //error occurs here

int OPairType::getX() const {
 return x;
}

int OPairType::getY() const {
 return y;
}

void OPairType::setX(int new_x) {
 x = new_x;
}

void OPairType::setY(int new_y) {
 y = new_y;
}

void OPairType::setValues (int new_x, int new_y){
 x = new_x;
 y = new_y;
}

OPairType operator + (OPairType lh, OPairType rh){
OPairType answer;

 answer.x = lh.x + rh.x;
 answer.y = lh.y + rh.y;

 return answer;
}

OPairType operator - (OPairType lh, OPairType rh){
OPairType answer;

 answer.x = lh.x - rh.x;
 answer.y = lh.y - rh.y;

 return answer;
}

bool operator == (OPairType lh, OPairType rh){
 return lh.x == rh.x && lh.y == rh.y;
}

bool operator != (OPairType lh, OPairType rh){
 return !(lh.x == rh.x && lh.y == rh.y);
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, OPairType c){
 out << "(" << c.x << ", " << c.y << ")";
 return out;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant:

```
OPairType::OPairType (int x, int y){ }
```

You can not only declare a member function outside the class. You need to define the body.